# Firmware bug when booting

Tags: updates

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr update
[sudo] password for mirror: 
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • SSD 970 EVO 250GB
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Embedded Controller
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade Intel Management Engine from 192.72.1757 to 192.90.2072?             ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Version 12.0.90.2072 (LVFS: 192.90.2072)                                     ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Problem Fixes                                                                ║
║                                                                              ║
║ • Intel CSME IPU 2022.1                                                      ║
║ • Mitigated the following security vulnerabilities under issues:             ║
║                                                                              ║
║ 20Q9S01Q00 must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of the   ║
║ update to avoid damage.                                                      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Perform operation? [Y|n]:  
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Restarting device…       [***************************************]
Writing…                 [***************************************]
Scheduling…              [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Restarting device…       [***************************************]
Waiting…                 [***************************************]
Successfully installed firmware
 • System Firmware
 • Thunderbolt host controller

An update requires a reboot to complete. Restart now? [y|N]:
```

When booting the following flashes in the top-left corner:

```
[    0.790342] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
```

Repeating command `sudo fwupdmgr update` shows the same device firmware requires update.

How do I install this device firmware update?

Comment: For Samsung SSD, Check firmware and see if newer version here: https://semiconductor.samsung.com/consumer-storage/support/tools/ Unless you have Windows do not use Magician. If 970 EVO ISO 2B2QEXE7 Check current version: ` udisksctl status`

Comment: $ udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung SSD 970 EVO 250GB 2B2QEXE7  S465NX0K925868J      nvme0n1

Comment: The revision matches that shown on the samsung.com support page. Not using Magician. Not using Windows host. 

The [Firmware Bug] is a result of installing "Intel Management Engine from 192.72.1757 to 192.90.2072". Similar problem has persisted with the previous similar firmware update.

How do I properly install the Intel Management Engine update?